# Modifying Data Set within a function but data set is not changed

Tags: r, for-loop, dataset, storage

My code is the following in R:

```
replaceNA<- function(myData,limit){
    numNA<- rowsum(is.na(myData))
    targetRows<- which(numNA<=limit)
    targetCols<- length(names(myData))
    for(row in targetRows){
        for(col in 1:targetCols){
            myData[row,col][is.na(myData[row,col])]<-1
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through each element in myData and replace all NAs of a row with 1 IF the row does not have more than the  number of NAs. I have tested my code with print statements and found that the iteration works perfectly (although not the most efficient code) and if I examine the modified myData by putting in a fix(myData) before the last bracket of the function, I see that my function worked perfectly(the NAs are replaced with 1s for the rows that meet the limit condition). However, when I examine myData after the function terminates, myData does not show the changes replaceNA made.

I know there is a problem in storing the modified myData but I am not sure how to store it properly.

Comment: Functions are like Las Vegas. What happens in the function _stays_ in the function (unless you explicitly return it).

Comment: Also, What is rowsum here? is it a user-defined function?

Comment: rowsum() exists within R: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rowsum.html

Comment: sorry for the extra comment, you are right, rowSums() must be used in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is not clear ( English problem). In any case you don't need a for loop here.

To compute the number of missing values for each row :

```
rowSums(is.na(myData))
```

Then you just test your condition and you replace all the row:

```
mm <- myData[rowSums(is.na(myData)) <= limit ,]
mm[is.na(mm)] <- 1
myData[rowSums(is.na(myData)) <= limit ,] <- mm
```

Comment: the condition is that if there are less than or equal to the limit(let's say 2 in this case) number of NAs in a row, then you replace all NAs within that row with 1. If there are more than 2 NAs in that row, you do NOT replace the NAs.

Comment: otherwise, your code is more concise than mine. I ended up scrapping the function and just putting the two lines of code in. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3749778 concise yes, but more important it is vectorized code so , faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your function explicitly return the modified data,

```
replaceNA<- function(myData,limit){
    numNA<- rowsum(is.na(myData))
    targetRows<- which(numNA<=limit)
    targetCols<- length(names(myData))
    for(row in targetRows){
        for(col in 1:targetCols){
            myData[row,col][is.na(myData[row,col])]<-1
        }
    }
    return(myData)
}
```

then assign the modified data. You could overwrite your old data

```
myData <- replaceNA(myData, limit = 2)
```

or make a copy to compare

```
myData_no_na <- replaceNA(myData, limit = 2)
```

You can also avoid the loop entirely, which is much more R-like. @agstudy's answer seems to be covering that approach nicely.

Comment: I understand that objects within a function only exist within the function body, however, this function is modifying a global variable. Isn't this the equivalent of a void function in java? So the modification should still be present even after the function terminates, or so I believe.

Comment: No! In the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm (R is functional, Java is not), functions don't have "side-effects", which means they don't modify the global environment. The function modifies a copy of the data you pass it, the original is unaltered.

Comment: ahhhh, I see, so all functions should return something or store something to a global variable otherwise it is lost when the function terminates. Thank you for your explanation. As you probably assumed, I just picked up R a couple days ago and every explanation helps a great deal!

Comment: Pretty much. Other functions don't return anything but have a desired side-effect (e.g., `plot()`, `print()` or `write.csv()`). Some functions do modify global variables (`options()`), but almost all user-defined functions shouldn't touch the global environment. You might want to check out the Functional Programming section of [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) if you want to read more about this aspect of R programming.